# How to define cascade delete in the Hybris items.xml?

Tags: cascade, sap-commerce-cloud

I want to remove child objects automatically on removable of the Parent object.

For instance, I have types Car and Engine. The car has an attribute Engine. When Car object is removed, Engine object that is bound to this Car should be removed automatically.

Thanks in advance, guys

Comment: https://wiki.hybris.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=141795383

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a question that is answerable?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions so you will be better prepared and able to ask a question that will be well received and more importantly **answerable**. This is not a *send me teh codez* site, that is now how this site works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the "partOf" modifier:

```
<itemtype code="Car" ...>
  ...
  <attributes>
    ...
    <attribute qualifier="engine" type="Engine">
      <persistence type="property" />
      <modifiers partof="true" />
    </attribute>
  </attributes>
</itemtype>
```

Can also be used with relations:

```
<relation code="CarToEngineRelation"...>
  <sourceElement type="Car" ...>
  </sourceElement>
  <targetElement type="Engine" ...>
      <modifiers partof="true"/>
  </targetElement>
</relation>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Johannes very well set the example.

Let me elaborate more on

### What is PartOf?

PartOf modifier is used to define the aggregation relationship between Parent and Child objects. To explain it better I would say PartOf is used to defining cascade delete. When we delete Parent object then all its child objects(partOf) will be deleted automatically.

You can define it at attribute or relation with help of modifiers tag. Like

```
<itemtype code="User"
          extends="Principal"
          jaloclass="de.hybris.platform.jalo.user.User"
          autocreate="true"
          generate="true">
    <deployment table="Users" typecode="4" propertytable="UserProps"/>
    <attributes>
        ...
        ...
        <attribute autocreate="true" qualifier="addresses" type="AddressCollection">
            <modifiers partof="true"/>
        </attribute>
        <attribute autocreate="true" qualifier="carts" type="CartCollection">
            <modifiers partof="true"/>
        </attribute>
    </attributes>
</itemtype>
```

If we remove a user, its all addresses & carts will be removed.

---

### find the detailed [post here](https://www.helphybris.com/2018/08/what-is-partof-modifier-in-hybris-items-xml.html)